# styling of google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-api-2

I have embedded my map in a website , Now I want to change color of google map to  `dark` , as given in google maps. I am trying to do this but don't know where to given style I have to apply
my code of init map is. I think I have to change in this

```
  _initMap: function() {
            var self= this, options  = this.options,
                centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(options.latitude, options.longitude);

            /**
             * map
             * @type {google.maps.Map}
             */
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.element[0], {
                zoom: parseFloat(options.zoom_level),
                center: centerPosition,
                minZoom: options.minZoom,
                maxZoom: options.maxZoom
            });

            this.storePopupTmpl = mageTemplate($(options.storePopupTemplate).html());

            /**
             * infor windopw
             * @type {google.maps.InfoWindow}
             */
            this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                //maxWidth: 250,
                //disableAutoPan: true,
                maxWidth: 450,
                minWidth: 350,
            });
```

**EDIT**  I am doing according to this

```
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ is just a tool that helps you create the JSON you need to style your map implementation.

You should read the [style reference guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference).

The easiest implementation is as follow. The JSON style you exported goes in the `styles` property of the [MapOptions object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions).

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  // Map Style JSON
  var blueStyle = [{
    'featureType': 'all',
    'elementType': 'labels',
    'stylers': [{
      'visibility': 'off'
    }]
  }, {
    'featureType': 'road',
    'elementType': 'labels.icon',
    'stylers': [{
      'visibility': 'off'
    }]
  }, {
    'stylers': [{
      'hue': '#00aaff'
    }, {
      'saturation': -50
    }, {
      'gamma': 1.15
    }, {
      'lightness': 12
    }]
  }, {
    'featureType': 'road',
    'elementType': 'labels.text.fill',
    'stylers': [{
      'visibility': 'on'
    }, {
      'lightness': 24
    }]
  }, {
    'featureType': 'road',
    'elementType': 'geometry',
    'stylers': [{
      'lightness': 85
    }]
  }];

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.368465, 4.903921),
    zoom: 10,
    styles: blueStyle
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize"
        async defer></script>
```